# Dismissing a navigation view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently working on a game for the iOS platform. The game's initial view controller is a login screen, and once the player logs in, he gets to a loading screen, and then a navigation view controller containing a table view with a list of current games. The storyboard's relevant view relations look like this:

[login screen] --modalsegue-> [loading screen] --modalsegue-> [navigation controller] --relationship-> [tableview (with logout button)]

I want to make a logout button at the bottom bar of the navigation view's [table view], which takes the player back to the [login screen]. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can dismiss, `self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController` or you can use `dismissToRootViewController`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. I will accept your answer as soon as I am able (6 minutes).

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold there is no such method called `dismissToRootViewController`

Comment: you saved me. +1 for you

Answer (score 8):

[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     UIBarButtonItem *btnLogout = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnOnClick:)];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnLogout;
}
-(void)btnOnClick:(id)sender
{
     [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I hope...This may help you...